# Vim visual mode search and replace

Tags: vim

When you run a search and replace on visual-line selected text, it shows this `:'<,'>s/foo/bar`

Is it possible to get it to show line numbers instead of <>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mapping to do this

```
xnoremap : :<c-u><c-r>=line("'<")<cr>,<c-r>=line("'>")<cr>
```

When you hit `:` in visual mode it will delete the `'<,'>` that is normally put there with `<c-u>`. Then it will insert the line number for the `'<` and `'>` marks separated by a comma. It does this with

```
<c-r>=line("'<")<cr>
```

where `<c-r>=` opens the expression register which allows you to type in an arbitrary expression and insert the result.

---

I don't recommend using this since it makes it almost impossible to repeat the visual selection command on a new region, since the history will now have line numbers instead of the marks. The line numbers can't change between invocations but the marks can.

Answer (score 0):

My [CmdlineSpecialEdits plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5865) has (among many others) a `CTRL-G '` mapping that changes symbolic ranges like `'<,'>` to the actual line numbers (e.g. `3,42`), and vice versa. It also corrects addressing out of bounds (<= 0 and larger than the last line number) and backwards ranges.